# How to restrict a SQL Server user to execute some stored procedures only?

Tags: sql-server, security

The goal is to have a user who can execute some stored procedures and nothing else. For example I don't want to allow the user to query `SELECT GETDATE()` or `SELECT 10 + 20` or anything else.

My main final goal is to prevent a malicious user to waste the power of server's CPU by calling a query in a loop. As I know this is somehow preventable in the code of stored procedures, for example by using a delay(`WAITFOR`) inside it but not for a query like `SELECT 10 + 20`.

How is this possible by SQL Server 2012?

Let me ask a better question:

Is there any way to limit the default "Public" user to execute only specified stored procedures and not query something like `SELECT 10 + 20` ?

Comment: RE "My main final goal is to prevent a malicious user to waste the power of server's CPU": the main goal should be to prevent malicious user from accessing the database. Do you have some specific problems with SQL injection attacks?
How do users currently connect to SQL Server?

Comment: If you want to limit CPU per user you can do so using [resource governor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor) But be aware of the issues you can create with it.

Comment: @Alex: There are some special situations in which we require to share one username with very limited permissions between all instances of our client application and yes we hide the password in application's source code but it's not a reliable method and a malicious user may find the password. Currently we are not worry about SQL injection attacks.

Comment: You could encrypt your config files using a certificate. This way the end user is not able to just use it.

Comment: @Preben: Then where should I store the private key of certificate and use it to decrypt my config files? We have no application (like web server or anything else) between client application and SQL Server.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://magenic.com/thinking/encrypting-configuration-sections-in-net) it’s for web configs but the same approach works for app configs, the security on the certificate should be set on the accounts running the application.